# Intellisense can't find namespace

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Im using VS code 1.18.1
with typescript 2.4.2 (workspace ver.)

in my tsconfig file I set the include property to point to my typings folder where I have a couple of d.ts files with namespaces in them

when trying to use a namespace in VSCode i get the following messages :

1. Cannot find namespace '{namespace}'
2. 'extends' clause of exported class '' has or is using private name ''

the namespace is define in one of the files in my typings folder but only if i use `/// <reference path="..." />` to the d.ts file the intellisense works.

I cannot use the `/// <reference path="..." />` in my ts files

Is there any other way to make the intellisense to work without the using Triple-Slash Directives?

Answer (score -3):

> Is there any other way to make the intellisense to work without the using Triple-Slash Directives?

Use a tsconfig.json file.

## More

Docs on compilation context : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/project/compilation-context aka the root of all "which files".

Comment: Im using tsconfig.json, i have a path to all my d.ts files defined under the include property 
in regarding to the compilation evrything is fine, compilation is passing 
the issue is with the intellisense

Comment: link is outdated